# Site was recently hacked, would like help on improving my login script

Tags: php, security, authentication, mysqli

Yesterday my site was hacked, the hacker managed to login to the admin area and post a blog which contained a redirect link to his website. So Im asking for a bit of help in making my login secure.

Here is my script:

```
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = md5_base64($_POST['password']);

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, permission FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($userid, $username, $password, $permission);
    $stmt->store_result();

    if(($numRows = $stmt->num_rows) > 0)
    {   
        $response_array['status'] = "success";
        $response_array['message'] = "Logged in";
    }
    else
    {
        $response_array['status'] = "error";
        $response_array['message'] = "Sorry, Wrong Username/Password Combination" .$password;                   
    }
```

Heres the md5_base64 function:

```
    function md5_base64 ( $data ) 
    { 
       return preg_replace('/=+$/','',base64_encode(md5($data,true))); 
    }
```

Any help, advice and improvements are greatly appreciated.

Comment: For starters, you know MD5 should almost never be used for actual security, right?

Comment: I think its not with this code, check if your server not compromised!

Comment: And you're sure, he didn't manage to get your password?

Comment: Would crypt be a better way instead of md5? The server was definitely not comprimised. The only way he/she managed to get in was through this login script. At the risk of getting laughed at admittedly the password was 'qwerty123' (*hides*) but i still dont know how he could have got my username. Which made me think my script is flawed.

Comment: You can start here https://www.owasp.org

Comment: It would be interesting to know what you are doing after the login. What is your sourcecode to check if a users has successfully logged in? Maybe there is a problem?

Answer (score 1):

**A little bit information regarding how attack happened is required.**

1. It may be the possibility of **SQL Injection** rather than programming
   defect.
2. Always sanitize your input before sending the query to database , a
   single quote can create a SQL Injection attack.
3. Watch for **default passwords or simple passwords** like admin ,
   admin123 , 12345 etc.
4. One can easily guess or can use Dictionary attack to crack it.

   Use Complex Passwords as well.
5. If you are using Database , use **Prepared Statement**  .

Regards

**Anshul Katta**

Comment: This is not an answer but just some irrelevant copypaste. (2) contradicts with (5) and the OP is already using (5), making (1) impossible - so, they need neither of these.

Comment: i have tried to answer it globally so that people coming to this post , not only the questioner is enlightened by the answer...if you have good answer  please post it...rather than complaining .Thank you

Comment: Erm... SQL injection is a programming defect.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your login script, save for the function md5_base64() which is quite silly. But from the SQL injection point of view it's innocent.
With such a password like 'qwerty123' one don't need a cunning injection to break through. A name, I suspect, is as easy guessable as a password.

Or there can be some other flaw. like silly cookie to remember the user or such

Answer (score 0):

The question you need to ask yourself - How did that person get the password?

Did he log into the actual machine? This can be prevented by a security audit and remove access to ftp/telnet - edit `/etc/inetd.conf` and remove unnecessary services. Also check daemons that are started upon boot - Google runlevels and what is started. Just use SSH to access the machine.

Then look at the database. MySql can be configured to only accept connections from certain IP addresses and use SSH. Also ensure that access to the database is via user accounts with known permissions for particular databases

Also check your firewall. This can prevent people accessing the machine remotely.

Then look at the configuration of the web server. Perhaps use HTTPS for access to the administration area.

Also follow the advice given by anshulkatta above